# 'Click to jump to the line' not working after upgrading to El Capitan

Tags: texmaker, mac

I upgraded to OS El Capitan and while everything seems to work with texmaker, the "click to jump to the line" is not working anymore.

Would love to hear if this happened to someone else and how you fixed it.
I tried unistalling and installing (my go to solution for all problems) but that didn't work.

Thanks!

Comment: I'd like to add: remove also non-English characters from file name and path.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://tex.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/130790)

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem and managed to solve it through these steps:

1. Go to Options>Configure TexMaker>Commands and insert `-synctex=1`under PdfLaTeX: pdflatex -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode %.tex
2. Make sure your current file is the master-file. You can set that in the options menu.
3. Make sure the name of your file and its path do not contain spaces and special characters.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

In case your PdfLaTeX has quotes around it for some reason and that was giving you trouble like it did for me, this is where I put the `-synctex=1-interaction=nonstopmode`.

```
.../texbin/pdflatex" **-synctex=1-interaction=nonstopmode** %.tex
```